# How to deal with map and unordered_map as the same object

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring

I'm making some kind of a library for printing data and I have this code.

```
struct io {
    template<class U, class V>
    static inline void print_map(const std::unordered_map<U, V>& m, const string& delimiter = " ") {
        std::stringstream sin;
        for (const auto& p : m) sin << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")" << delimiter;
        print_stream(sin, delimiter.size());
    }

    template<class U, class V>
    static inline void print_map(const std::map<U, V>& m, const string& delimiter = " ") {
        std::stringstream sin;
        for (const auto& p : m) sin << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")" << delimiter;
        print_stream(sin, delimiter.size());
    }
private:
    static void print_stream(const std::stringstream& sin, const int ignore) {
        const std::string result = sin.str();
        std::cout << result.substr(0, result.size() - ignore) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

My question is, Is there some sort of a way to make the `print_map` function a single function where I don't need to overload it, maybe something like this

```
struct io {
    template<class U, class V>
    static inline void print_map(const maps_super_class<U, V>& m, const string& delimiter = " ") {
        std::stringstream sin;
        for (const auto& p : m) sin << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")" << delimiter;
        print_stream(sin, delimiter.size());
    }
private:
    static void print_stream(const std::stringstream& sin, const int ignore) {
        const std::string result = sin.str();
        std::cout << result.substr(0, result.size() - ignore) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace everything with just a `typename T`:

```
template<typename T>
static inline void print_map(const T& m, const string& delimiter = " ") {
    std::stringstream sin;
    for (const auto& p : m) sin << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")" << delimiter;
    print_stream(sin, delimiter.size());
}
```